# Matching individual points in two different sets of coordinates

Tags: opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching, coordinates, matching

I asked my question in math.SE but no answer, so I ask it here:

I have to match some 2d sets of points to an another 2d set of points (as ground truth) and find the outliers. In other word I have to match each single point to (maximum) one of the points in the ground truth set.

As an example consider that I want to match each star of **Ursa Minor**, to one of **Ursa Major**'s stars, but in a situation that one of them may have 8 or 9 stars and the other one has 7 stars. How could I catch those unmatchable points (e.g. the 8th one)?

I found out Ransac and Procrustes are good methods for matching points but (as I'm using the opencv's functions) it needs the two input sets to have equal sizes! which mine don't.

I added these image samples (consider black circles as points):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add example images so it is easier to understand.

Comment: estimateRigidTransform  accepts images as input.